# Sketch / Illustrator: Creating H8 Pentagonal Tiling?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, sketch-app

[image: type 8 pentagonal tiling]
<sub>(source: [jaapsch.net](https://www.jaapsch.net/tilings/images/large/P5-type8.png))</sub>

I'd like to create type 8 pentagonal tiling in illustrator and--if possible--Sketch 3. I first tried tracing in sketch which obviously gave imprecise results.

Is this level of precision possible in Sketch? In Illustrator?

If so, how do I handle the borders and create the shapes? Should they overlap?

Googled tiling and couldn't find anything--help would be appreciated!

https://www.theguardian.com/science/alexs-adventures-in-numberland/2015/aug/10/attack-on-the-pentagon-results-in-discovery-of-new-mathematical-tile

Answer (score 2):

You may need to use scripting to create the pattern exactly. Both Sketch and Illustrator can be [controlled via scripts](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html)

You can find the formula and some [sample rendering at Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pentagon+type+15+tiling&rawformassumption=%22ClashPrefs%22+-%3E+%7B%22PeriodicTiling%22,+%22PentagonType15Tiling%22%7D). If you pay for the pro subscription, you can also directly download the tiling bit of the pattern in multiple formats.

Not really a complete answer, but hopefully this'll get you in the right direction. :)

Comment: Thanks Ville, I'll check it out. I'll investigate and attempt myself, but hoping someone has done it before and can provide more specifics!